# Using a for loop to append to array in Excel VBA Basic

Tags: excel, vba, append

How do I loop through a sheet using `IF` statements, and for each `TRUE`, append it to an array?

Basic example, if `Cells(y, 1).Value` is greater than 0, then append 1 to an array and do so through the given range creating an array with multiple values of 1 (given multiple Cells(y, 1).Value(s) is greater than 0).

This is how I've created loops before.

```
For y = 2 To LastRow

    On Error Resume Next
    If Cells(y, 1).Value > 0 Then   
        Cells(y, 2).Value = 1     ' Instead of populating Cells(y,2) with "1" IF true, I want to append the value to an array
    ElseIf Cells(y, 1).Value = 0 > 0 Then 
        Cells(y, 2).Value = 2
    Else
        Cells(y, 2).Value = 0
    End If

Next y
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to first dimension an array

```
Dim myArray() as Integer
```

And inside your loop, keep track of the number of elements the array will have

```
Dim myCount as Integer
```

Then inside your loop you must increment this counter and redimension the array so you can add to it

```
If Cells(y, 1).Value > 0 Then   
    myCount=myCount+1
    Redim Preserve myArray(1 to myCount)
    myArray(myCount)=1
```

The `Preserve` reserved word is important as it prevents the contents of your array from being reinitialized as you add items to it.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the quick, clear and helpful reply!

Comment: My pleasure. Glad I could help.

Comment: @Vichtor remember to mark Matt's answer as the correct one. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more info.

Comment: Some hints to your answer: a) *"..inside your loop you must increment this counter and redimension the array"* 
- Just dimension the array to the count of rows/items (minus 1 as it's 0-based) and 
eventually do the `Redim Preserve` once outside the loop. b) BTW Assigning a range's value 
to a temporary variant array and looping through it would be less time consuming 
than to loop through a range. c) Why do you assign `myArray(myCount)=` to `1` instead of the range value?
d) Why do you fill item values of a zero-bound array starting from 1? - @MattCremeens